# MySQL Count number of substring occurrences in column

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL, I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of a substring in a column, for each row.

In the example table below, the string "art" appears three times in the Terms column, so it would have a count of 3.

Example Table:

```
TERMS
art
artistic
painting
elephant
art deco
paint
paintings
```

Desired Output:

```
TERMS      COUNT
art        3
artistic   1
painting   2
elephant   1
art deco   1
paint      2
paintings  1
```

**Edits:**

As a starting point, I know that:

```
SELECT terms, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY terms
```

will output number of occurrences for each full term string. For substring matching, I think this may involve a subquery.

Tried the following, but every count was 1.

```
SELECT terms, ROUND((CHAR_LENGTH(terms) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(terms, terms, ""))) / CHAR_LENGTH(terms)) AS count
FROM table
GROUP BY terms
```

Comment: Please share  your trials with us.

Comment: your replace function replacing each row's terms by it-self; look at Suggestion 1 and 2 in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write this by first writing a query that just returns a list of terms we  want to return. For example:

```
 SELECT t.terms
   FROM `table` t
  GROUP BY t.terms
```

Then wrap that in parens and use it as an inline view...

```
SELECT w.terms
  FROM ( SELECT t.terms
           FROM `table` t
          GROUP BY t.terms
       ) w
 ORDER BY w.terms
```

With that, we can do a join operation to look for matching rows, and get a count. Assuming a guarantee that `terms` doesn't contain underscore (`_`) or percent (`%`) characters, we can use a `LIKE` comparison.

Given that every term in our list is going to appear at least one time, we can use an inner join. In the more general case, where we might expect to return a zero count, we would use an outer join.

```
SELECT w.terms
     , COUNT(1) AS `COUNT`
  FROM ( SELECT t.terms
           FROM `table` t
          GROUP BY t.terms
       ) w
  JOIN `table` c
    ON c.terms LIKE CONCAT('%', w.terms ,'%')
 GROUP BY w.terms
 ORDER BY w.terms
```

In the `LIKE` comparison, the percent signs are *wildcards* that match any characters (zero, one or more).

If there's a possibility that `terms` does contain underscore or percent characters, we can escape those so they aren't considered wildcards by the LIKE comparison. An expression like this should do the trick:

```
 REPLACE(REPLACE( w.terms ,'_','\_'),'%','\%')
```

So we'd have a query like this:

```
SELECT w.terms
     , COUNT(1) AS `COUNT`
  FROM ( SELECT t.terms
           FROM `table` t
          GROUP BY t.terms
       ) w
  JOIN `table` c
    ON c.terms LIKE CONCAT('%',REPLACE(REPLACE( w.terms ,'_','\_'),'%','\%'),'%')
 GROUP BY w.terms
 ORDER BY w.terms
```

---

There are other query patterns that will return the specified result. This is just a demonstration of one approach.

---

NOTE:  In the example in the question, every `terms` that is a substring of another `terms`, the substring match appears at the *beginning* of the terms. This query will also find matches where the term isn't at the beginning.

e.g. `dartboard` would be considered a match to `art`

The query could be modified to match `terms` that appear only at the *beginning* of other `terms`.

**FOLLOWUP**

With the example data, returns:

```
terms      COUNT     matched_terms
---------  --------  -------------------------
art               3  art,art deco,artistic
art deco          1  art deco
artistic          1  artistic
elephant          1  elephant
paint             3  paint,painting,paintings
painting          2  painting,paintings
paintings         1  paintings
```

In addition to the `COUNT(1)` aggregate, I also included another expression in the select list. This isn't required, but it does give some additional information about which terms were considered to be matches.

```
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.terms ORDER BY c.terms) AS `matched_terms`
```

NOTE: If there's a possibility that `terms` contains backslash characters, we can escape those characters as well, using another REPLACE

```
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( w.terms ,'\\','\\\\'),'_','\_'),'%','\%')
                 ^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Very nice answer! but dont you need a `GROUP BY w.term` also before `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @MichaelK:  yes. we do need a GROUP BY. *DOH!*   (answer edited to incorporate the correction.)

Comment: Incredible answer! Thank you. Not only did this accomplish my goal, but I learned a lot while studying your answer. I ran it on a table with 26k rows, and the query took 175s to complete.

Comment: @OBreaux1: The LIKE comparison with the percent wildcards is going to require that every row in `table` be examined, for every `terms` entry. If those are longish rows in the table (lots more columns in the table) an index ... ON `table (terms)` may benefit performance, if the query is satisfied entirely from the index.

Comment: @OBreaux1: This query returns the number of *rows* that include a `terms`; the count is increment by 1 if there is a match. For example, "dartmart" would match "art", but the count would be incremented by one. Not two, even though "art" appears two times.